# Inability to Shelve with SQL Query Windows Unsaved in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, shelving

As I was wrapping up my work-day, I wanted to shelve my changes in TFS before I went home as I encourage all developers to do.  All my changes were saved to disk, and I had a number of SQL query windows open that I'd been using as scratch-pads to write queries against the database.

Unfortunately, it wouldn't let me shelve my legitimate changes without saving these files to disk - and I have no intention of saving them, they're just scratch-pads to mash out some SQL queries.

Is there a work-around for this?  The queries are never saved and have never been added to source control.

Comment: see [this uservoice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2836547-allow-me-to-check-in-code-even-if-i-have-unsaved) for a similar issue.